# GraphQL Endpoint returns 400

Tags: django, graphql, postman, graphene-python

I have a django app built with graphene and I have a problem running a simple `POST` query for the `GraphQL` endpoint, it keeps returning a `400 Bad request syntax`.

[image]

but it should work since I don't have any problems running the query from the endpoint http://localhost:8000/graphql-dev

[image]

and I can't see any issues in the way I send the postman request. 
I looked online for suitable solutions but couldn't find any that would help.

Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: 
I still didn't manage to see why I'm having this issue with postman, but here are some observations:

1. first, i changed the request to GET (since in `graphql`, `query` is for `GET` and `mutation` for `POST` - sorry, I missed that)
2. I tried the same request with postman (which didn't work) and with insomnia (which did)

   - with postman 
     [image]
   - with insomnia 
     [image]

What's weird is that if i check my django console the requests look the same.

[image]

EDIT2: okay, I figured it out...removing the `Content-Type` `application/json` did the trick. Now it works with postman as well.

Comment: What is your Content Type header? `application/json`?

Comment: @DanielRearden yes

Comment: Might be a postman issue, I tried the same request with insomnia and it worked

Comment: @KeykoYume, It happened to me, environment variable is causing the issue sometimes, directly we cannot see the parameter. Two things to check 1)remove env. variables and pass url and variables as it is. OR 2)Open Postman console while calling the request and check URL and request parameters